# IP Camera in ASP.NET Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

In an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project, I want to display an image of an IP camera on a web page. I have not had this experience so far, but I searched for RTSP, but it was unsuccessful.

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer :

```
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV;

    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCameraImage()
    {
        string ImagePath = "/Camera/image.png";

        var capture = new 
                VideoCapture("rtsp://user:password@ip:port/cam/realmonitor? 
                channel=1&subtype=0");

        var frame = capture.QueryFrame().ToImage<Bgr, byte>();

        frame.Save(imagePath);

        var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);

        return File(fileBytes, "image/png");
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).